# A summation identity over prime fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, summation, finite-fields, perfect-powers

Let $p > 2$ be a prime. Can someone prove that for for any $t \leq p-2$ the following identity holds

> $\displaystyle \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} x^t = 0$

Comment: Hint: The units of $\mathbb{F}_p$ form a cyclic multiplicative group of order $p-1$.

Comment: ... so if $g$ is a generator of the multiplicative group, then $g^t\neq1$, but $\sum_xx^t$ and $\sum_x(gx)^t$ are equal...

Comment: Another standard way to use a primitive root is to turn our sum into a geometric series.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: Look more closely! In the linked question we are not working in a field, and the summation variable is the **exponent** not the **base**.

Comment: @User84559: Care to flesh out your hint to an answer/Hint? :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: André Nicolas has said as much as one can say without explicitly giving a solution, so I'll post an answer.

Comment: @User84559: True. I have actually used this result on many an answer, but IIRC I always just stated that this follows from the geometric sum formula. Therefore I was a bit reluctant to step up to the plate, but I'm glad that you did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t\in\{1,\ldots,p-2\}$ and let $g\in\Bbb{F}_p^{\times}$ be a primitive root. Then $g^t\neq1$ and $g^{p-1}=1$, so
$$\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}x^t=\sum_{k=0}^{p-2}g^{kt}=\frac{1-g^{(p-1)t}}{1-g^t}=0.$$

Answer (score 4):

Because of $t < p-1$, there exists an $a\in\mathbb F_p^\times$ with $a^t\neq 1$. Now
$$
\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} x^t
= \sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} (ax)^t
= a^t \sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} x^t.
$$
So
$$\underbrace{(1 - a^t)}_{\neq 0}\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} x^t = 0$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} x^t = 0.$$